# how to get started with google app-engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I m starting to build python application in windows platform using google appengine

whats the steps to debug and run my application

Comment: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/overview.html

Answer (score 2):

On Windows I use [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/).

Once you've installed that, run it, go to the Plugins tab and get Pydev.

Pydev has inbuilt support for google app engine - so you can create an app engine project, and then run or debug it. See these posts for more details:

http://pydev.blogspot.com/2009/05/testing-on-pydev-146-google-app-engine.html

http://pydev.blogspot.com/2009/05/pydev-146-released-google-app-engine-on.html